# Warning Unkown Prop

Tags: reactjs

Using `React.createClass({})` I could easily pass props to a child component. How to do it with `React.Component{}`?

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  // imported Child and in the render:
  render(){
    return <Child name={this.state.foo} />
  }
}

export default class Child extends React.Component {
}
```

> Warning unkown prop 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of passing prop is the same, however you need to check whether you are defining the state variable correctly. Look at the below implementation. There might be a set of reason for the above errors namely;

> Are you using {...this.props} or cloneElement(element, this.props)?
>   Your component is transferring its own props directly to a child
>   element (eg.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html). When
>   transferring props to a child component, you should ensure that you
>   are not accidentally forwarding props that were intended to be
>   interpreted by the parent component.
>
> You are using a non-standard DOM attribute on a native DOM node,
>   perhaps to represent custom data. If you are trying to attach custom
>   data to a standard DOM element, consider using a custom data attribute
>   as described on MDN.
>
> React does not yet recognize the attribute you specified. This will
>   likely be fixed in a future version of React. However, React currently
>   strips all unknown attributes, so specifying them in your React app
>   will not cause them to be rendered.

Also check which version of react are you using and that you are correctly setting up the react to work with ES6 syntax.

**PS:** I am using version 0.14.8 for the below snippet

```js
 class Parent extends React.Component {
  // imported Parent and in the render:
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      foo: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
  render(){
    return <Child name={this.state.foo} />
  }
}

 class Child extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete explanation of the warning: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Basically, it seems that you are passing the `name` prop down to an HTML element that doesn't support a `name` attribute.